# Why does sudo apt-get build-dep not work for emacs24?

Tags: software-installation, apt, packages

this is my first post on this SX Forum.

After doing some searching myself (and failing), I wanted to ask why the command `sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24` fail on a Pi running Raspbian Jessie?

The output I receive is the following error: `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

What I am wondering then is:

1. Why doesn't Raspbian's deb and deb-src not have emacs24's dependencies upstream from Debian?
2. Is there another way to enable the command for emacs24? If not, how can I find all the dependencies needed for building emacs without X Windows (aka GUI) support?

   Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My system config is

> Linux raspberrypi 4.4.13+ #894 Mon Jun 13 12:43:26 BST 2016 armv6l
>   GNU/Linux

Please follow the below steps and it should get things ready for you.

```
1. sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
2. Un comment the line 
   deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Now the file will look like

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source' 
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Perform a `sudo apt-get update`

Now your command `sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24` should work. Its just enabling the builds from `deb-src` doing the trick.

Comment: I wish all Linux distributions had source repositories configured by default.  I am not sure if there is a huge downside if they did.  The ability to quickly download and read the exact source (including any distro patches) of a package that is present on my system is immensely useful.

Comment: Can confirm it also works for Raspbian Stretch